# WP sub-domains multisite: How to change default permalink structure for new sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, multisite

I have a **WP multisite set up with *sub-domains*** for all sites.

I would like the **URL structure** for each new site to be:

subdomain.maindomain.com/*post-name*

For instance: subdomain.maindomain.com/hi-world

I've been struggling with this for a day and a half, and I hope somebody here can help me. I have read a LOT of info, and tried with editing the default theme's **functions.php** and also adding a custom plugin in **mu-plugins**. But I have not succeeded yet.

So the regular setting for permalinks is now: /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

But I'd like to have: /%postname%/

Ok, I have tried many different things. [This](https://www.trickspanda.com/set-wordpress-permalinks-functions-php/) is probably the closest to success (?):

```
// set permalink
function set_permalink(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/');
}
add_action('init', 'set_permalink');
```

In the functions.php I have this for adding standard pages to the new blogs/ sites automatically:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'wpb_create_my_pages', 10, 2);

// create new page
  $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'     => 'My title',
    'post_name'      => 'The name',
    'post_content'   => 'The content here',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_author'    => $user_id, // or "1" (super-admin?)
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'menu_order'     => 10,
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status'    => 'closed',
 ));
```

So in this I have tried the 'set_permalink' function, but it doesn't work.

I have also tried making my own mu-plugins plugin, but haven't got that working neither.

When I Google I keep finding solutions that require the new blog's owner to log in and save the permalink structure, but I simply want the permalink structure to be the same for all new blogs/ sites.

**How can I set the default permalink structure for new sites?**

Thanks for any pointers or code that can help me with this!

Comment: https://wpmudev.com/forums/topic/how-to-change-the-default-permalink-structure-for-new-wpmu-sites/ ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271662/multisite-network-how-to-change-permalink-structure-programmatically-on-new-blo ?

Comment: @O.Jones thank you. Both of these I have tried, but for some reason they don't take effect on my multisite. I'm not sure why.

Comment: It is the second one that I’d recommend, however using `activate_blog` or `wp_insert_site` hooks instead. To be clear, you have an MU plugin, and you are testing this when adding new sites, they won’t retroactively apply to any.

Comment: Thanks again. I redid every step with the two links you posted to, and the solution here worked the second time I tried: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271662/multisite-network-how-to-change-permalink-structure-programmatically-on-new-blo So I must have had a type some where. 

I made the mu-plugins plugin once more, and now it works every time. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thank you. I got the second one to work. Must have been a typo in my first tries, though without any error. Not sure where. I just deleted and started from scratch. So you would change 'wpmu_new_blog' to 'wp_insert_site' ? Have I understood this correct?

Comment: The former is deprecated and will raise warnings. It was officially replaced by the latter.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, awesome insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future proofing this question with an answer, and for reference for others:

1. I created a new sub directory in /wp-content/ named "mu-plugins", so I had /wp-content/mu-plugins/
2. In "mu-plugins" I created a file named "rewritepermalinks.php"

In it I put:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Permalin Structure Edit
 * Description: Edit the permalinks structure on new multisite sites
 * Author:      
 * License:     GNU General Public License v3 or later
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', function( $blog_id ){

switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
restore_current_blog();

}, 10 );
?>
```

This then worked for me on Wordpress 5.8.3 and with multisite enabled. The solution was found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271662/multisite-network-how-to-change-permalink-structure-programmatically-on-new-blo) and also mentioned in the comments for the question. I had tried it once before but must have had a typo because it didn't work the first time.

I have tried to use 'wp_insert_site' in stead, but haven't got that to work. There is a hint in the comments [here about wp_insert_site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_site/) that might be of value to get this working.

For now the above code works for me as a MU plugin.